# Can send MQTT message from command line but cannot format message correctly in python

Tags: python, json, mqtt

So I am using the esprfid project to control access to a door.
That is all working.
I am using a Raspberry PI running Buster as a message broker and am trying to write a python script to send the open door message.

If I use the following command from a terminal window

```
mosquitto_pub -h 192.168.0.22 -t maindoor -m '{"cmd":"opendoor","doorip":"192.168.0.45"}'
```

the broker outputs

```
Client mosqsub|1227-hackrfid2 received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'maindoor', ... (42 bytes))
{"cmd":"opendoor","doorip":"192.168.0.45"}
```

and the door opens.

Following some tutorials I have created the following simple script:

```
from paho.mqtt import client as mqtt_client
import time
import json

broker = "192.168.0.22"
port = 1883

client_id = "rfidManager"
topic = "-t maindoor -m "

openDoor = json.dumps({"cmd":"opendoor","doorip":"192.168.0.45"})

def connect_mqtt():
    def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
        if rc == 0:
            print("Connected to MQTT Broker!")
        else:
            print("Failed to connect, return code %d\n", rc)

    client = mqtt_client.Client(client_id)
    # client.username_pw_set(username, password)
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.connect(broker, port)
    return client


def publish(client,msg):
    
    result = client.publish(topic, msg)
    # result: [0, 1]
    status = result[0]
    if status == 0:
        print(f"Send `{msg}` to topic `{topic}`")
    else:
        print(f"Failed to send message to topic {topic}")
   


def run():
    client = connect_mqtt()
    client.loop_start()
    publish(client, openDoor)

def main(args):
    run()
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

This outputs

```
Connected to MQTT Broker!
```

Send `{"cmd": "opendoor", "doorip": "192.168.0.45"}` to topic `-t maindoor -m`

when I run it and the broker outputs

```
Client mosqsub|1227-hackrfid2 received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0, '-t maindoor -m ', ... (45 bytes))
```

{"cmd": "opendoor", "doorip": "192.168.0.45"}

I have been trying to sort this on and off for a couple of days and cannot spot the error.
Has anyone got any suggestions as to what to try?

Steve

Comment: your Topic field needs to JUST be the topic....not the comandline flags from mosquitto_pub!  So: `topic = "maindoor"` will work.

Comment: thanks for the response, I have tried that,
topic = "maindoor "
and also added a delay in 
def run():
    client = connect_mqtt()
    client.loop_start()
    time.sleep(10)
    publish(client, openDoor)

Neither of which have made a difference, so still confused